# Camera not centre on player sprite (monogame)

Tags: c#, camera, xna, monogame

Im trying to make a game in Monogame and have followed a camera tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_SPRT7DAeM&t=180s (which works great) The only problem is that when it zooms it zooms to the corner of the player sprite as you can[image] see here:

Here is my code

camera.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace RpgGameCrossPlatform
{
    class Camera
    {
        private Matrix transform;
        public Matrix Transform
        {
            get { return transform; }
        }

        private Vector2 centre;
        private Viewport viewport;

        private float zoom = 3;
        public float rotation = 0;

        public float CentreX
        {
            get { return centre.X; }
            set { centre.X = value; }
        }

        public float CentreY
        {
            get { return centre.Y; }
            set { centre.Y = value; }
        }

        public float Zoom
        {
            get { return zoom; }
            set { zoom = value; if (zoom < 0.1f) zoom = 0.1f; }
        }


        public Camera (Viewport newViewport)
        {
            viewport = newViewport;
        }

        public void CameraUpdate(Vector2 position)
        {
            centre = new Vector2(position.X, position.Y);

            transform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-centre.X, -centre.Y, 0)) *                                             
                                                 Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(Zoom, Zoom, 0)) *
                                                 Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(viewport.Width / 2, viewport.Height / 2, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

player.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace RpgGameCrossPlatform
{
    class Camera
    {
        private Matrix transform;
        public Matrix Transform
        {
            get { return transform; }
        }

        private Vector2 centre;
        private Viewport viewport;

        private float zoom = 3;
        public float rotation = 0;

        public float CentreX
        {
            get { return centre.X; }
            set { centre.X = value; }
        }

        public float CentreY
        {
            get { return centre.Y; }
            set { centre.Y = value; }
        }

        public float Zoom
        {
            get { return zoom; }
            set { zoom = value; if (zoom < 0.1f) zoom = 0.1f; }
        }


        public Camera (Viewport newViewport)
        {
            viewport = newViewport;
        }

        public void CameraUpdate(Vector2 position)
        {
            centre = new Vector2(position.X, position.Y);

            transform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-centre.X, -centre.Y, 0)) *                                             
                                                 Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(Zoom, Zoom, 0)) *
                                                 Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(viewport.Width / 2, viewport.Height / 2, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

and game.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace RpgGameCrossPlatform
{
    class Camera
    {
        private Matrix transform;
        public Matrix Transform
        {
            get { return transform; }
        }

        private Vector2 centre;
        private Viewport viewport;

        private float zoom = 3;
        public float rotation = 0;

        public float CentreX
        {
            get { return centre.X; }
            set { centre.X = value; }
        }

        public float CentreY
        {
            get { return centre.Y; }
            set { centre.Y = value; }
        }

        public float Zoom
        {
            get { return zoom; }
            set { zoom = value; if (zoom < 0.1f) zoom = 0.1f; }
        }


        public Camera (Viewport newViewport)
        {
            viewport = newViewport;
        }

        public void CameraUpdate(Vector2 position)
        {
            centre = new Vector2(position.X, position.Y);

            transform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-centre.X, -centre.Y, 0)) *                                             
                                                 Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(Zoom, Zoom, 0)) *
                                                 Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(viewport.Width / 2, viewport.Height / 2, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

help would be appreciated as well as some general tips as I am new :)

Comment: Looks like you've accidently placed your camera.cs code on all three classes.

Answer (score 4):

This could mean that the camera is focussing on the player's default position, which is always on top-left.

You should set a center position (called the 'origin') for the player, this could be done by adding half of the player's width (for x) and height (for y) at the current default position it's focussing at.